# Vega-lite Multiple Measures + Normalized Stacked Bar Chart + Overlay percentages as text

Tags: vega-lite

Trying to extend the solution to [Vega Lite: Normalized Stacked Bar Chart + Overlay percentages as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66636702/vega-lite-normalized-stacked-bar-chart-overlay-percentages-as-text) but for a multi-measure repeat layer chart.  I'm unable to get the text values to appear, with each attempt at "plugging in" `"field": {"repeat": "layer"}` where I think it should go throwing error: unsupported object: {"repeat":"layer"}.

What I have working now is the chart, without the labels.  What I **want** is to add the percentage labels as I was able to do in the second chart:
[open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAJgAyoDQjgUwgczhiTUxABIBnAY1wFsBDJbGGAB0sQHouA3HfAwB0+CPACuAIyEQA9lxr0GfAQwC0AGzE4+AViEArSrIB2ILFAYwmiULwYbxOSkgDaoAAoAnWbwgnqHGYAeQA5cxAAESsgxBAAKQYTAAI0NAiAZQdnZgB2CIBFGABPZgBGXRAAXwxPHz8A2JAwiOiYJoAxHElU1HSsLI0cuORCkuZRmrrff0DmACEAYVaY5kSUtNRM7Jc4gGYx0rjKqZBvGcaF5aw2zu7e-pBB4ZAADkPy96qAXRqQLxwbBwViQoA0DGKOC8bieOw+vywlCB1FBIEYXgA1sxJAxoVgcAFZFB-PhUQAPVGWGDiOiogFAkFxcGQ6F-EpA5gmWR0fwOapYI6gBj4fAAwTtZiUGkRABmEBwGigdMBwOITIhUP5IHZTQAjuIkjAxFYIPwIpRrNQsXEuV5GFoAF5BLBGmBDZgZGnJWQy5IAWWBUoBWuosg0smhthAcoVSri5wacyqyaqQA)
[image]

I have the same data but in a single measure layout with labels working fine
[open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAJgAyoDQjgUwgczhiTUxABIBnAY1wFsBDJbGGAB0sQHouA3HfAwB0+CPACuAIyEQA9lxr0GfAQwC0AGzE4+AViEArSrIB2ILFAYwmiULwYbxOSkgDaoAAoAnWbwgnqHGYAeQA5cxAAESsgxBAAKQYTAAI0NAiAZQdnZgB2CIBFGABPZgBGXRAAXwxPHz8A2JAwiOiYJoAxHElU1HSsLI0cuORCkuZRmrrff0DmACEAYVaY5kSUtNRM7Jc4gGYx0rjKqZBvGcaF5aw2zu7e-pBB4ZAADkPy96qAXRqQGC8SUoADNZF46G5QAZZP4GPh8F5VO1ISBZGxmJRxBCsMCIDgNFBmM8XFgGLt-rJrBpqt8sAjZOI2JIjq4oqtfrUQNQHNRxBpVnFLDAsa4AOTE0XfZJcZJCrFCGCUhwRMnMYGA6gwORmH5YHABWRQfz4JCgI6gXH4wlxdUMTXaiIlNhNACO4iSWusWv4EUo1moAGtmCYwYwtAAvIJYT1DJAmPkaP4AD1NIEtBOYt0dEDoOAAqiYxMxijgGODTPBHcVncwwUaTMro2JY4h4xoNKSkxBdqB+ZJ8QBBEz4FtqACcqCqfzrOC8qfT1rTGq1pl9YOIgucgRM9ZNf2osg0YPneIzcXODTmU6w-JLc8Q7hAjC8QbikjL1U5z9foCdTXaSbEBYKaIGQUBHGUZBJCOsSTnqBq7qmB5HvedgOE4zBgHA2ifv8OCAUhphGiuZi2HhfrMHKdBCLa9qmMkAB8AC8ySoEIkERAuarLg60bVq67omJ6VgQD6OKhlYzBCKgACkuH2I4TTVFOvxAA)
[image]

What I tried was to joinaggregate and calculate in totalSales, totalQty, fractionSales and fractionQty.  Then, instead of `"repeat": {"layer": ["Sales", "Qty"]}` I thought to `"repeat": {"layer": ["totalSales", "totalQty"]}`

Comment: Do you just want labels on your first link? Also, please mark your old questions as solved.

Comment: Edited to add emphasis on what I want, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Edited the "what I want" screenshot/mockup trying to be more clear in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from David Bacci, the solution here was to `fold` the data first, then add two `joinaggregates`, one for the total per measure (totalKey) and a second for the per-province per measure total (totalProvince). This allowed for the single column fraction to hold what was needed for the text, without having to repeat layers.

[view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Ig7glgJgLgFiAXAJgAyoDQjgUwgczhiTUxABIBnAY1wFsBDJbGGAB0sQHouA3HfAwB0+CPACuAIyEQA9lxr0GfAQwC0AGzE4+AViEArSrIB2ILFAYwmiULwYbxOSkgDaoAAoAnWbwgnqHGYAeQA5cxAAESsgxBAAKQYTAAI0NAiAZQdnZgB2CIBFGABPZgBGXRAAXwxPHz8A2JAwiOiYJoAxHElU1HSsLI0cuORCkuZRmrrff0DmACEAYVaY5kSUtNRM7Jc4gGYx0rjKqZBvGcaF5aw2zu7e-pBB4ZAADkPy96qAXRqQGC8SUoADNZF46G5QKCNFA3E8dh9frUQAZZP4GPh8F5VO1ISBZGxmJRxBCsMCIDgYcx7I4glgGLt-rJrBoANI4Uo-LBY2TiNiSI6uEAAaw5ICRoFR6Mx2MEuMQ7nxhLixNJIHJlNhcRpTgiDOYMGZDnODTmXJAPL5ArhotKWBNsyCEpA1Ac1HEGlWcQAFJYYCTXAByQ0sh2NQPfZJcZJ+klCEMOdnFACUesZwMB1BgcjM5pwAVkUH8+CQoAAHqX1RSqXFbRESmwmmCiyYHPWxENmNUsEcodWterM9nTPXio3mABHcRJbPWbP8PUynFNVURSjWajC5gmMGMLQALyCf2bOC8lY1NcHDCzObXYOIcSgzkCJhbJaqf09xVPeMYXi3cSSAwZ5YPm1CFsWlbgRoYLnv2zBhnMWANk0O50OiGjVB+yJ-gBoAoQaOBlsQWDQbBcRgHA2jdiAYEQSYJa2P8REPn2mrMBm17DmYZK7lYzAAH6En8xTBMCwKUDgrEgLGEKIGUqAfj8VRAA)
[image]

```html
{
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Province": "ON", "Date": "Jan 2020", "Sales": "7", "Qty": "15"},
      {"Province": "ON", "Date": "Feb 2020", "Sales": "2", "Qty": "2"},
      {"Province": "BC", "Date": "Jan 2020", "Sales": "3", "Qty": "5"},
      {"Province": "BC", "Date": "Feb 2020", "Sales": "8", "Qty": "18"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["Sales", "Qty"]},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "totalKey"}],
      "groupby": ["key"]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "totalProvince"}],
      "groupby": ["key", "Province"]
    },
    {"calculate": "(datum['totalProvince'] / datum.totalKey)", "as": "fraction"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "key",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": ""
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "fraction",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "stack": "normalize"
    },
    "order": {"field": "fraction", "sort": "descending"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {"color": {"field": "Province", "type": "nominal"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "fraction", "format": "~p"},
        "yOffset": {"datum": 10}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

[image]

```
{
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Province": "ON", "Date": "Jan 2020", "Sales": "7", "Qty": "15"},
      {"Province": "ON", "Date": "Feb 2020", "Sales": "2", "Qty": "2"},
      {"Province": "BC", "Date": "Jan 2020", "Sales": "3", "Qty": "5"},
      {"Province": "BC", "Date": "Feb 2020", "Sales": "8", "Qty": "18"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["Sales", "Qty"]},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "Sales", "as": "total"}],
      "groupby": ["Date"]
    },
    {"calculate": "(datum['Sales'] / datum.total)", "as": "fraction"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "key",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": "",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "stack": "normalize"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {"color": {"field": "Province", "type": "nominal"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "fraction", "aggregate": "sum", "format": "~p"},
        "detail": {"field": "Province"},
        "yOffset": {"datum": 10}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Province": "ON", "Date": "Jan 2020", "Sales": "7", "Qty": "15"},
      {"Province": "ON", "Date": "Feb 2020", "Sales": "2", "Qty": "2"},
      {"Province": "BC", "Date": "Jan 2020", "Sales": "3", "Qty": "5"},
      {"Province": "BC", "Date": "Feb 2020", "Sales": "8", "Qty": "18"}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["Sales", "Qty"]},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "Sales", "as": "total"}],
      "groupby": ["Date"]
    },
    {"calculate": "(datum['Sales'] / datum.total)", "as": "fraction"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": "",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "stack": "normalize"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {"color": {"field": "Province", "type": "nominal"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "color": "white"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "fraction", "aggregate": "sum", "format": "~p"},
        "detail": {"field": "Province"},
        "yOffset": {"datum": 10}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: David, sorry if I phrased my question poorly.  What I want is the example that I posted with measures on the x-axis (i.e., Sales, Qty), with the percentage labels.  I think what you posted was another way of doing what I already had working with date on the x-axis.

Comment: Just change the x-axis to key. I'll update now to show you.

Comment: OK - this is cool, the idea of using fold really helped, thank you!  Note that your solution does not display the correct percentages, but using your code as a model, I was able to get it to work.  How should I post the "correct solution" to the original problem for the next person who comes along?

Comment: You can add your own answer. Don't forget to mark as solved.